# if\else not working as expected with network location

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, copy

i have been trying to get this to work but it either does not follow the if/else or it just goes through the the copy and echo and never goes to else if the file does not exists

```
IF EXIST "\\netowrklocation\folder\*.*" (
    copy "\\netowrklocation\folder\*.*" "\\remotepc\folder" >nul
    echo \\netowrklocation\folder\*.*
    echo copied \\netowrklocation\folder\*.* >>%log%
 ) ELSE ( 
    Echo The file was not found.
    echo try again later
    goto repeat
 )
echo Files Copied
echo Files Copied >>%log%
```

i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, but what i want it to do is check if their is a file in \netowrklocation\folder\, if their is copy it and do the echo/log

if not echo file not found, and go to the repeat area (not shown, not relevant)

Comment: Check for the file then. Read your error messages instead of hiding them.

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].  Show us the output and tell us what you expected.

Comment: Why not use Robocopy?, which supports UNC paths natively. Example: `@"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "\\networklocation\folder" "\\remotepc\folder" /IS /IT /LOG+:"%log%" /NDL /NP /XX`. Please open a Command Prompt window and enter `"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" /?` to read its usage information and adjust your options as/if necessary.